# PDO mutliple fetch_assoc from one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, pdo

I have one SQL query where I get some data from DB and I wanna use multiple fetch_assoc inside 2 WHILE loops and also outside WHILE loop:

```
$test = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM test WHERE userid=:userid");
$test->execute(array(':userid' => $_GET["id"]));
$testing = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

below this code I have one of the conditions:

```
if ($testing["name"] == $_POST["name"]) {

    echo "Already exist !";

}
```

and later on the same page, making a list (this is used twice on that page in two different HTML forms):

```
while ($testing = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

       echo "<option> ".$testing["name"]." </option>";

}
```

this WHILE doesn't work, because one FETCH_ASSOC already exist.. is there an option, how to make this work without creating a new SQL query ? I need exactly 2 WHILE loops for making a lists, and 1 fetch without loop for protection entry conditions.. and making 3, the exact same SQL queries, seems to me as incorrect approach.. am I wrong ?

Comment: Fetch once in an array using `$data = $test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, then use the `$data` array for looping and what not, you don't need the while construct at all.

Comment: hm, I think, I don't understand, what's you mean..

Comment: Your query returns some data. You use `while($testing = test->fetch...)` style of obtaining that data. When you do that once, you can't repeat it (which is why you have the problem). What I'm suggesting is to fetch the data ONCE into one variable. Then use the variable as many times as you want.

Comment: I catch that, but I don't know, how do you exactly mean "loop in array".. if I make a FOR loop: $rows = $test->rowCount(); for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows, $i++), every single data what I get, is the very first row of results (repeating for "number of rows" times)..

Comment: Ok, now I done it.. using example from your first comment, I change fetch() to fetchAll() and make foreach to loop array.. so, thanks for help..

Comment: I'm glad you got it, good luck with further programming :)